# Mercurial fails while commiting/updating/etc. using Mercuriual+TrueCrypt+MAC

Tags: python, mercurial, truecrypt

While trying to work with Mercurial on project located on TrueCrypt partition I always get en error as follows:

```
** unknown exception encountered, details follow
** report bug details to http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/
** or mercurial@selenic.com
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.5.2+20100502)
** Extensions loaded: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 27, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 16, in run
    sys.exit(dispatch(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 30, in dispatch
    return _runcatch(u, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 50, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(ui, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 470, in _dispatch
    return runcommand(lui, repo, cmd, fullargs, ui, options, d)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 340, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 521, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 475, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 469, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 401, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 3332, in update
    return hg.update(repo, rev)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/hg.py", line 362, in update
    stats = _merge.update(repo, node, False, False, None)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/merge.py", line 495, in update
    _checkunknown(wc, p2)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/merge.py", line 77, in _checkunknown
    for f in wctx.unknown():
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/context.py", line 660, in unknown
    return self._status[4]
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 156, in __get__
    result = self.func(obj)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/context.py", line 622, in _status
    return self._repo.status(unknown=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1023, in status
    if (f not in ctx1 or ctx2.flags(f) != ctx1.flags(f)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/context.py", line 694, in flags
    flag = findflag(self._parents[0])
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/context.py", line 690, in findflag
    return ff(path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dirstate.py", line 145, in f
    if 'x' in fallback(x):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

It is worth mention that Mercurial works perfectly if project is not located on TrueCrypt partition.

Configuration:
MacOS X 10.6.3
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.5.2+20100502)
Python 2.6.5

Have anyone of you generous people able to help me? :)

Comment: um... don't use a TrueCrypt partition? Also dunno if this is relevant but http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/05/truecrypt-on-2618-kernels/.

And why are you using encryption if you have nothing to hide? ;)

Comment: Nothing to hide?  How about your company's codebase.  In some situations, consider that losing your laptop could result in *millions* of dollars of damages.  Truecrypted: zero.  Truecrypting a coding project makes a *ridiculous* amount of sense in a business setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was added in `1.5.2` (sorry about that), we released `1.5.3` shortly afterwards, please use it.